# Login to Airbnb via CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to do API calls to Airbnb, but you must be logged in to make these calls, and with no public API, I am left to try and come up with a solution.

I am first trying to login via CURL, I am trying to use this piece of code but I'm not having much luck.

```
$url = "https://www.airbnb.co.uk/login";
$postinfo = "email=".$username."&password=".$password;

$cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
//for certain features, set the cookie the site has - this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html_data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html_data;
```

The response I get is:

```
{
success: false,
redirect: ""
}
```

Where am I going wrong ( I have declared the vars, username, and password but have obviously left that out).

Comment: what response are you getting?

Comment: added the response now

Comment: Try adding some more headers to pretend you're a real browser. the `Accept` header might be helpful since it tells the server what sort of response you can work with.

Comment: @BCLtd as far as I can see, the login request goes to `https://www.airbnb.co.uk/authenticate` and you first need to navigate to the login page to grab the authentication token from `authenticity_token`input filed to use on the authenticate page request

Comment: So, use CURL to grab the value from the hidden field 'authenticity_token' on page on https://www.airbnb.co.uk/login and then post user/pass on https://www.airbnb.co.uk/authenticate is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can't login to Airbnb by curl because Airbnb uses google captcha which can't be resolved. This is why it returns `success: false`.

If you want to do something with their application you should try to go [here](https://www.airbnb.nl/partner) and apply as partner in order to use their API.

Comment: I cannot see the captcha when I access https://www.airbnb.co.uk/login ?

Comment: If i login in the browser it returns a google captcha